# Scan new manually added controllers,, when xml based spring mvc has already been loaded

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-mvc

I am working on a project where we are using spring mvc as a web framework.
It has an xml-based configuration and starts up first. 
But also I have plugins which I can add to my project manually while working with it. Each plugin describes an API with all his @Controller-s and Models.

I managed to register these API-s in my Spring configuration
(

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(classNames);
        ctx.refresh();
```

),
 but how can I kind of "wake up" my spring and say please scan all these controllers.

I have an ExceptionHandler for all my API-s that's why I need to scan them all to connect these Controllers with the handler.

I have tried this, but it did not work.

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan(packageName);
        ctx.refresh();
```

I get no error during the execution.

Comment: Have you tried to include that in your xml config file ? <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

Comment: Yes, I added component scan for the base package of all the plugins but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use @RestController annotation for your controller class which was defined all APIs

```
@RestController
public class exampleController {

}
```

Use @Component annotation for other component classes

```
@Component
public class Validations {

}
```

As well as you can use **@Service** annotation for business layer which is defined business logic and use **@Repository** annotation for the class which access database.

To enable above mentioned annotations, you need add below mentioned dependancy If you are using "maven" to build the project. otherwise add all jar files to the project related with below dependancy

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you need to handle exceptions you need create below mentioned class with @ControllerAdvice annotation. You can handle specific method for the each exception. (Example: NullPointerException)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends RuntimeException {

@Autowired
ResponceBuilder responseBuilder;

@JsonIgnore
private HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;

public ExceptionHandler() {
    super();
}

@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(Example.class)
public ResponseEntity<Response> 
NullPointerException(NullPointerException e) {

    log.info("Invalid Data: {}",e.getErrorMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBuilder.build(e.getErrorCode(), 
    e.getErrorMessage()), status);
}
```

Comment: I do not use spring-boot. And I have already tried to put Controller and ControllerAdvice annotations. However it did not help me. :\